# NGINX SSL in Windows Server 2019 (WIN10) issue! --HTTPS--

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, windows-server

Here is my case, hope somebody can help me out..

I am using AWS EC2 free tier, I choose windows server (I am already using the other free Linux instance for the frontend with ssl), this windows server is successfully running my NODE JS API in HTTP with NGINX.

I bought a SSL certificate and its already activated, but when trying to request to https it return nothing (api.puertoexpress.net took too long to respond) **http://api.puertoexpress.net is working correctly**

So I have tried a few things:

- I opened the https 443 port in the AWS console.
- I opened the 443 port in the inbound firewall rule (allow edge transversal).
- I disabled the IIS manager because I read that the IIS might be blocking the 443 port by default
  **In powershell:** *Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online | ? featurename -like "IIS" | Disable-
  WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -Remove*
- I checked which ports my windows instance is using
  **In CMD:** *netstat -ab*

  [image]

This is my **NGINX conf** located in C:/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;


 server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    server_name api.puertoexpress.net www.api.puertoexpress.net;

    ssl_certificate     api_puertoexpress_net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}



}
```

- My open ports in AWS console.
  [image]

**What else can I do? any help is welcome.**
*PD: I have tried several NGINX configurations, I have done research but cant make it work.
I tried self-signed certifications, and I even bought a positiveSSL certificate, but nothing is working. what am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Check the logs. Is the request reaching your server?

Comment: @ArielAlvarado for http request the access log is:

157.100.76.164 - - [23/Jun/2021:18:52:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 39 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"

there is no log for the https request, nor in access or error logs, what can it try?

Comment: @RafaelEchart the answer you gave looks good, but the question header needs to be more descriptive of what your problem was, something like "NGINX SSL - website took too long to respond".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an question answer, but I found that in the NGNIX settings the maxSize of the upload was very short for what I was trying, so I had to set a bigger chunkSize in the NGNIX setting file :)

Comment: Can you show the change you made to NGINX settings? What is the name of file and its location in directory? I, too, cannot run NGINX to work on https.